# plotly multiple lines chart with a varying dataframe

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to make a function that plots all a Dataframe content.
DF Sample:

```
print(df2)
                               Close       Close       Close
Date                                                        
2018-12-12 00:00:00-05:00  53.183998   24.440001  104.500504
2018-12-13 00:00:00-05:00  53.095001   25.119333  104.854973
2018-12-14 00:00:00-05:00  52.105000   24.380667  101.578560
2018-12-17 00:00:00-05:00  50.826500   23.228001   98.570381
2018-12-18 00:00:00-05:00  51.435501   22.468666   99.605042
```

Python:

```
fig = px.line(df2, x=df2.index, y=df2.columns[1:])
```

I'm trying to plot it but get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

My data frame may have various numbers of columns, so I need my code to plot all columns.

By the way:

```
print(df2.columns[1:])

Index(['Close', 'Close'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the column names. I used the code above with unique column names for the above data and got the following:
[Plot obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3agX.png).

Also, you can use the date column as your x-axis in the plot. Plotly will generate a timeseries chart for the same.